# Prometheus query for metrics generation

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I'm collecting metrics with Prometheus, specifically histograms of outgoing requests from my service to various routes.

Here's an metric example:

```
southbound_request_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.05",target="api.token-machine.fra.co",method="GET",route="http://api.token-machine.fra.co/states",status_code="200",type="total"} 96
```

I wish to display in a grafana metrics by route & by latency percentile.

This is the query I wrote:

```
histogram_quantile(0.90 , sum(rate(southbound_request_duration_seconds_bucket{marathon_app_path=~"$instance_path", route=~"$route", env="mars"}[1d])) by (route))
```

but for some reason i does not generate any data. If I replace

```
by (route)
```

to

```
   by (le)
```

It generates data but every percentile appears 3 times (one per each route) but it does not display the actual route.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
histogram_quantile(0.90 , sum by (route, le) (rate(southbound_request_duration_seconds_bucket{marathon_app_path=~"$instance_path", route=~"$route", env="mars"}[1d])))
```

so that `le` is preserved for histogram_quantile, and it's also broken out by route.

Comment: Tried the query, getting the same results as before.